# How to implement critical sections on ARM Cortex A9 for GCC, no OS?

Tags: c, arm, interrupts, cortex-a

I am porting some legacy code from an ARM926 core to CortexA9.  This code is baremetal and does not include an OS or standard libraries, all custom.  I am having a failure that appears to be related to a race condition that should be prevented by critical sectioning of the code.

I want some feedback on my approach to see if my critical sections may not be correctly implemented for this CPU. I am using GCC. I suspect there is some subtle error.

Also, is there an opensource library that has these types of primitives for ARM (or even a good lightweight spinlock/semephore library)?

```
#define ARM_INT_KEY_TYPE            unsigned int
#define ARM_INT_LOCK(key_)   \
asm volatile(\
    "mrs %[key], cpsr\n\t"\
    "orr r1, %[key], #0xC0\n\t"\
    "msr cpsr_c, r1\n\t" : [key]"=r"(key_) :: "r1", "cc" );

#define ARM_INT_UNLOCK(key_) asm volatile ("MSR cpsr_c,%0" : : "r" (key_))
```

The code is used as follows:

```
/* lock interrupts */
ARM_INT_KEY_TYPE key;
ARM_INT_LOCK(key);

<access registers, shared globals, etc...>

ARM_INT_UNLOCK(key);
```

The idea of the "key" is to allow nested critical sections, and these are used at the beginning and end of functions to create reentrant functions.

Thanks!